# Conditions on a constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

Is this condition in the constructor correct or is there a better way to do this?

```
class Foo {
    public: Foo(int y) {
        if (y < 0 || y > 99)
           cout << "Error! Invalid input" << endl;

        else
            x = y;
        }

    private: int x;
    };
```

Comment: Correct in what context?  If you're trying to make sure `y` is between `0` and `99` inclusive, it's fine.  Note that you still create an object.

Comment: Better way of doing what?

Comment: You might want to read about exceptions in your favorite C++ textbook.

Comment: Make `y` `unsigned`, then you don't have to use the `y < 0` check.

Comment: Maybe I've to trow an exception if the input is wrong, that's all

Comment: @0x499602D2 That's not particularly good advice.  We don't know what `y` represents, but if it's a numeric value, you definitely don't want to use `unsigned`.  (Using `unsigned` won't prevent the caller from passing a negative value.)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Exceptions are certainly a possibility, but depending on what the check failing means, `assert` may be more appropriate.

Comment: But what if I wanted the object not to be created if the y value is y<0 or y>99?

Comment: @W4lker, are you suggesting that `assert` would still create the object, even though the process would abort?

Comment: Then it's either an exception or `assert`.  What does it mean if the `y` value is wrong?  If it means that someone upstream has made an error, then `assert` is usually the better solution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general pattern in C++ to validate an object upon construction (i.e. to prevent creating an invalid object) is to throw an exception in the constructor. This way you can guarantee that if you have an object of type Foo it will be correctly initialized or not be created at all.

So you would do something along the lines of:

```
class Foo{
    public: Foo(int y) {
        if (y < 0 || y > 99)
           throw std::invalid_argument("y out of range");
        x = y;
    }

};
```

And upon instantiation you could catch the exception like this:

```
try
{
    Foo f(100);
    // do stuff with f
}
catch(std::invalid_argument& e)
{
    std::cout << "Construction of Foo failed" << std::endl;
}
```

If you don't catch it, it would bubble up and you could either catch it on a higher level or not at all, which would lead to an abort and exit the application. In general, exceptions should be caught at a place where it's obvious how to properly react to the exceptional circumstances (like displaying an error to the user in the simplest case and continuing with execution).

Comment: You don't _have_ to catch the exception, often the best thing to do with exceptions is just let them propagate and unwind the stack.

Comment: @JonathanWakely You don't have to catch them immediately, but if you don't ever catch them, `abort` is preferable.

Comment: @JamesKanze, yes, but in a library sometimes it might be best to leave catching them to the application calling the library, so it's in someone else's code. My point is that adding `try`-`catch` around the object's construction to catch them immediately is not necessarily a good style of coding: catching the exception far away, not locally, might be better. The answer says "you would have to catch the exception" which is what I was commenting on.

Comment: I changed the text a bit to indicate that you don't *have* to catch the exception.

Answer (score 4):

No.  If you have preconditions for the constructor, you can
check them, but if they fail, you should either throw an
exception or abort, not just output to `std::cout`.  Using 
`assert( y >= 0 && y <= 99 )` would be the typical way of doing
this.  (You should never output error messages to `std::cout`.)

Answer (score 2):

In your case, despite the error message, your constructor will still "work" - it will create object, but with invalid state. You may use exceptions in order to prevent creation of your object, so you will not have a problem with the existing objects of invalid state.

```
class InvalidInputException: public std::exception {
      // ...
};

class Foo{
    public: Foo(int y) {
        if (y < 0 || y > 99)
           throw InvalidInputException();
        x = y;
    }

};

// Test:


try
{
    Foo f(param);
}
catch(InvalidInputException& e)
{
    std::cerr << "Invalid input!" << std::endl;
}
```

Also, you don't need to create your own exception class. Standard library may have a suitable exception type for you, for example [std::runtime_error](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/runtime_error) or [std::logic_error](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/logic_error) (and their subclasses).

Answer (score 1):

You may want to employ the factory design pattern for something like this.  It would look something like this:

```
class Foo 
{
   private:
      int x;

      Foo(int y) 
      {
         x = y;
      }

   public:
      static Foo* GenerateFoo(int y)
      {
         Foo* newFoo = NULL;

         if(y >= 0 && y <= 99)
            newFoo = new Foo(y);

         return newFoo;
      }
}
```

This will cause no creation to occur if your input was out of range, and will instead return a NULL pointer.  Note that this particular implementation restricts storage of Foo objects to the run-time heap, and is overly simplified for example purposes.  More information is available about [how to implement the Factory Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern).

Comment: Why would he want to do something like that?  It means that he cannot create instances on the stack.

Comment: It's use dependent.  I'll add a link with more information.  This is really just an overly simple example of what this pattern does.

Comment: Yes, but the pattern isn't a good solution to his problem.

Comment: I would argue that it depends on the scenario.  It can be applied as a defensive technique to avoid invalid object creation in a situation where out of range data isn't truly exceptional.  Depending on your inclination for when you should/shouldn't use exceptions, it may be helpful.  Ultimately the question is very generic, so mentioning additional design patterns which may be of use with the actual situation may be helpful.  That was my thought process, at any rate. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another approach. This exact code assumes you do not want to throw exception from constructor, but instead want to give a chance to check validity, and throw exception only if invalid value is actually *used*. Using this approach can be justified, if initializing an invalid value is a "normal" situation, not anything "exceptional", otherwise it'd be better to throw directly from constructor.

```
class Foo { 

public: 

    Foo(int y) : 
        valid(y >= 0 && y <= 99), 
        x(valid ? y : -1) // use -1 as invalid value marker
    { 
        // note: doing cout output from constructor is... unusual
        if (!valid)
            cout << "Error! Invalid input" << endl;
    }

    bool isValid() {
        return valid;
    }

    int getX() {
        if (!valid) throw something;
        return x;
    }

private:
    bool valid;
    int x;
}
```

Note how that code also uses constructor initializer list. In this case order of member variables `valid` and `x` is important, `valid` must be before `x` because its value is used when initializing `x`.